# php include is not working in echo

Tags: php, html, image, css

I want to add include into echo with variable and css and image, but its not working. Please help.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['sharebutton'])) {
    $share=$_POST['sharetext'];
        $share=$share;
        echo '<div id="content">'.'<img src="img/sharepropic.png"/>'.$share.include('likecomment.php').'</div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: $share=$share? Really?  You can't concatenate an include. You'll need to do that as multiple lines.

Comment: Because they don't know how to use the code formatting here?

Comment: Yes, I don't know because i just start to learn php, and that's the reason I am here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to assign output from an include to a variable you can do this:

```
ob_start();
include('likecomment.php');
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo '<div id="content">'.'<img src="img/sharepropic.png"/>'.$share.$out.'</div>';
```

Comment: thank. i got it. Just i need to take another variable for include then only i can add this, right?

Comment: @krishnaTORQUE welcome to stack overflow. When somebody answers your question be nice and upvote & accept his answer so others know not to post answers :)